# lua macros for second keyboard

Tags: lua, macros, autohotkey

I am trying to use a second keyboard as a Macro Board, I am using the program Lua Macros and an AutoHotkey script. I was wondering if anyone knew how to print text through this. For example when I press the 'o' key on my second keyboard 'Hello World' would be written instead if I were working in google chrome or other programs.

Comment: show some code. read [ask]. "I was wondering if anyone knew how to print text through this" is not a problem you will get much help for here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use 2 different keyboards, then you could try to use HIDMacros. This program can still work together with AHK and it allows you to define hotkeys PER keyboard. Something AHK can't. In the past I've used HIDMacros together with a USB numpad so that I had 15+ separate keys (without needing to use Shift, Control and Alt combinations.

Video:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XKq7vjKgcJY

Website:  http://www.hidmacros.eu/

Apparently the developer has stopped support, but that should not mean that you can't use it.

Comment: They stopped support of hidmacros because they considered luamacros as a better option. https://github.com/me2d13/luamacros